# Share database and methods in apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Can any one know how to share database and methods between iPhone app and Watch Kit ?

I have researched and checked with below URLs:
http://koreyhinton.com/blog/communicate-between-watchkit-extension-and-app.html

http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/03/29/share-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app-with-realm/

But it gives about to share textual data with use of the method "handleWatchKitExtensionRequest".

Also most of code is in Swift language.

I want to know to share common database and methods between iPhone app and Apple Watch and in Objective C language.

Can anyone has any useful links or step-by-step guide to achieve this.

Thanks for help in advance.

But not getting any clue about to display video on apple watch.

So, is it possible to display mp4 video on apple watch or it is not possible.

Please help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Someone already answered your question re: video in the other question you asked. I should warn you that this question, as presently worded, will likely be closed. Questions regarding off-site resources and such are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To share data between the parent iOS app and the WatchKit extension, you have to set up a `Shared App Group`. Here you can use `NSUserDefaults`, `CoreData` etc. as you would normally, but it's available to both apps. Setting it all up is a long process, but once you get the hang of it it's not hard.

There's information on that topic in the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html) by Apple, and a [quick Google search](http://goo.gl/ahelcs) yields hundreds of results as well.

As of now I don't believe you can play video on the Apple Watch (unless you convert it into a sequence of images, which is fully possible to do in the parent app and then send it to the watch app). However, WWDC starts today and they will update WatchKit with more functionality. Playing `.mp4` videos might be one of them.

### **EDIT 1:**

WWDC 2015 just finished, and some of the changes there affect the correctness of my original answer. Here's an updated answer incorporating some of the new features of *watchOS 2*.

To share data between the parent iOS app and the WatchKit extension, you can no longer set up a `Shared App Group`. The correct way to do this now is using the `Watch Connectivity Framework`, basically sending data back and forth between the apps. This is because, unlike before, the Watch App now runs on the Watch itself as opposed to on the iPhone.

You can also show short video clips on the Watch, using a `WKInterfaceMovie` object.

You can read about that, and all the other additions to watchOS 2, in the [watchOS 2 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/ManagingYourData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH12-SW6)